# Finding local maxima within an array with conditions [JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to find a solution the following code challenge that meets all of the requirements and could use some help:

> ```
>      var ex1 = [5, 5, 2, 1, *4*, 2, *6*, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7];
>                // {pos:[4,6], peaks:[4,6] }
>      var ex2 = [3, 2, 3, *6*, 4, 1, 2, *3*, 2, 1, 2, 3];
>                // {pos:[3,7], peaks:[6,3]}
>  var plateau = [1, *2*, 2, 2, 1];
>                // {pos:[1],peaks[2]}
> ```
>
> 1. Find the local maxima or "peaks" of a given array but ignore local
>         maxima at the beginning and end of the array.
> 2. If there is a "plateau", return the position and value at the 
>         beginning of the "plateau."
> 3. Any plateaus at beginning and end of the array should be ignored.

My proposed solution uses the reduce function to look at the elements in the array before and after the current element. If these values are less than the value of the current element, the current element is a peak. "Peaks" at the edges of the array are ignored because they do not satisfy either the first or second criteria.

```
function pickPeaks(array) {
  return array.reduce((res, curr, i, arr) => {
    if(arr[i-1] < curr && curr > arr[i+1]) {
      res["pos"] = res["pos"] ? res["pos"].concat([i]) : [i];
      res["peaks"] = res["peaks"] ? res["peaks"].concat([curr]) : [curr];
    } 
    return res;
  },{});
}
```

However, this solution fails to find plateaus.

If I change my "right side" conditional logic to `curr >= arr[i+1]` it finds plateaus but does not ignore "edge" plateaus like so:

```
var plateau = [1, *2*, 2, 2, 1];
      correct // {pos:[1],peaks[2]}
    var ex1 = [5, 5, 2, 1, *4*, 2, *6*, 2, 1, 2, *7*, 7];
    incorrect // {pos:[4,6,7], peaks:[4,6,10]}
```

What am I missing here? How can I check if a "plateau" is at the edge of the array or not?

Comment: why is in `plateau` a peak?

Comment: You are ignoring edge repeated elements. From a edge perspective, ```[5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7]``` is the same as ```[5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 7]``` (removed the first 5 and the last 7)

Comment: @NinaScholz According to the terms of the problem, the first position of the `plateau` is considered a `peak` but only if it does not appear at the edges of the array.

Comment: @muZk Repeated elements i.e. `plateaus` at the edges are not considered `peaks` according to the definitions in the problem.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that you are only checking if `curr <= array[i+1]` without checking if array[i+1] is in fact a edge plateau.

Comment: @muZk That is correct. But `curr <= array[i+1]` will then ignore all peaks since elements on either side of the current element can equal it. I'd have to then check if `curr<=array[i-2]` and `curr<=array[i+2]` and so on until a smaller value was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `while` loop for getting the end of a plateau.

```js
function getLocalMaxima(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, v, i, a) {
        var j = i;
        while (v === a[++j]);
        if (a[i - 1] < v && (a[i + 1] < v || a[i + 1] === v && a[j] < v)) {
            r.pos.push(i);
            r.peaks.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, { pos: [], peaks: []});
}


var ex1 = [5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7],  // { pos: [4, 6], peaks:[4, 6] }
    ex2 = [3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],  // { pos: [3, 7], peaks: [6, 3]}
    plateau = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1];                   // { pos: [1], peaks[2] }
    
console.log(getLocalMaxima(ex1));
console.log(getLocalMaxima(ex2));
console.log(getLocalMaxima(plateau));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Would you mind explaining this last bit of conditional logic?
`a[i + 1] === v && a[j] < v`

Comment: the is the plateau check with the earlier while loop.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I'm asking is what its checking for. Looks like its checking to see if the next element is equal to the current element and if the element in the loop is less than the current element? Is that correct?

Comment: right. it finds the end of the plateau by checking the iterating element with the value. if the next element after the same element group is smaller, then an memorizable plateau is found.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to remove plateaus at the end in advance, and a minor correction on your updating the result of peaks:

```
function trimEndingPlateaus(array){
 var end = array.length -1;
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length -1; i++){
    if (array[array.length - 1 - i] === array[end]) end--;
    else break;
  }

  return array.slice(0, end);
}

function pickPeaks(array) {
  return trimEndingPlateaus(array).reduce((res, curr, i, arr) => {
    // find peaks

    if(arr[i-1] < curr && curr >= arr[i+1]) {
      res["pos"] = res["pos"] ? res["pos"].concat([i]) : [i];
      res["peaks"] = res["peaks"] ? res["peaks"].concat([curr]):[curr];
    }  
    return res;
  },{});
}
```

Test cases:

```
var plateau = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var ex1 = [5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7];    
var ex2 = [3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3];

console.log(pickPeaks(plateau));
//Outputs: {"pos":[1],"peaks":[2]}

console.log(pickPeaks(ex1));
//Outputs: {"pos":[4,6],"peaks":[4,6]} 

console.log(pickPeaks(ex2));
//Outputs: {"pos":[3,7],"peaks":[6,3]}
```